# Powershell command, to get users with expiring passwords in the next month or 30 days?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm having the hardest time getting the following output from powershell. The console just stops at the blinking cursor like the command is running, but I wait 20 min or so, and I still have no output, both in the powershell console, as well as when I try to export as a csv. I'm using the following command:

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountExpiring -DateTime "01/29/2017" | where {$_.ObjectClass -eq 'user'} | FT Name,ObjectClass -A | Export-Csv C:\temp
```

Could someone help? I've scoured the internet to no avail.

Comment: Try again without `FT Name,ObjectClass -A |`

Comment: Not only should you eliminate the `format-table`, you haven't specified the filename you think you have.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `format-table` inappropriately. Don't use **any** `Format-*` cmdlets if you need to process the data after that point - formatting makes that impossible. Always save formatting for the very end, and only for user presentation.

Also, you're going to end up with a file in your `C:\` root directory named `temp` that's not entirely usable as a CSV file, at least from Excel and other readers, because additional information is going to be inserted by `Export-CSV`. This will be eliminated by the `-notypeinformation` switch.

Additionally, you can speed this up by specifying the `-UsersOnly` switch for `Search-ADAccount` and skipping the `where-object` loop - the pipeline is really useful, but constructs like this can slow it down. Filter your data as far to the left as possible, and if you can do it inside a cmdlet that offers a filter, do it there.

Corrected script which should work as you expect:

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountExpiring -DateTime "01/29/2017"  -UsersOnly | select-object -Property Name,ObjectClass  | Export-Csv C:\temp\expiring.csv -NoTypeInformation;
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if this isn't perfect code, but this script will get you accounts expiring within the next 7 days. You can change the $DaysAhead variable to alter the time frame.

```
 $maxPwdAge=(Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy).MaxPasswordAge.Days; 
 $daysAhead = 7;
 $dateMin=(get-date).AddDays(-$maxPwdAge);
 $dateMax=$DateMin.AddDays($daysAhead); 
 Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False -and PasswordLastSet -gt 0} –Properties * | where {($_.PasswordLastSet) -ge $dateMin} |where {($_.PasswordLastSet) -le $dateMax} | select CN,EmailAddress,passwordLastSet | Format-Table;
```